# Nginx does not have access to centos path

Tags: nginx, php, centos6, php-fpm, path

Sorry for the rather confusing title, I am trying to understand this error.

I have a php file, inside a folder like `site.com/src/app/index.php` and this `site.com` folder is placed in `/var/www/html/` in a CentOs 6.5 running Nginx, and PHP-FPM.

So, the problem is that whenever I use any of the path functions and constants like `__DIR__`, `getcwd()`, `realpath()` inside `index.php` I would expect the full path to be as

`/var/www/html/site.com/src/app/` but, only `site.com/src/app/` gets returned. It is as if, that php/nginx does not know about `var/www/html/` folder.

I event went to the `app/` dir and was able to get the full path using `sudo pwd` but for some reason, php is not reading it.

I would like to know why this is happening, and how to fix it?

Comment: Are you running nginx in a chroot jail configuration? This would be the expected behavior of such a configuration.

Comment: Well, the thing is I am a noob. I followed [the Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-nginx-mysql-php-lemp-stack-on-centos-6) guide to install it altogether.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the example configuration I see at the Digital Ocean documentation you've linked, I suspect the following line is where your issue is coming from:

```
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME   $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
```

Or, rather, from a missing or incorrect root directive in one of the parent blocks. Then again, I'm not sure this is the behavior you'd see in such a case...I feel like it would give an error rather than run the script with incorrect results, but I don't have much experience with nginx.

See: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#fastcgi-path-in-script-filename

If you're still not sure how to proceed, please add your configuration for both nginx and the php-fpm configuration.